# Shortcut for converting array into map based on attribute

Tags: javascript, node.js

While working on `nodeJs` scripts, I find myself having to do the below often.

```
import _ from 'lodash'
let humans = [ {id: 'abc', name: 'Somebody 1'}, {id: 'xyz', name: 'Somebody 2'}];
let abcName = _.find(humans, {id: 'abc'}).name
```

Is there an existing function that I can use to convert humans array into a map based on id so that i can just call without using `lodash` and without having to write my own code to convert?

```
let humans = [ {id: 'abc', name: 'Somebody 1'}, {id: 'xyz', name: 'Somebody 2'}];
let humansConvertedToMap = convertToMap(humans, 'id')
let abcName = humansConvertedToMap[id].name?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to map it into a hash map with id attribute.

```
let humansMappedToId = humans.reduce(function(acc, val) {
    acc[val.id] = val;
    return acc; 
}, {});
```

The same could be done with `_.reduce` but `_.tranform` would be even simpler.

```
let humansConvertedToMap = _.transform(humans, function(m, v){
    m[v.id] = v;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that can do it for you:

```
const arrayOfObjectsToMapByKey = (arrayOfObjects, key) =>
  arrayOfObjects.reduce((map, currentObject) => {
    let k = currentObject[key];
    if (map[k]) {
      throw new Error("Repeated object key. Error thrown to stop overrides.");
    }
    map[k] = currentObject;
    return map;
  }, {});
```

So you can do what you wanted:

```
let humans = [ {id: 'abc', name: 'Somebody 1'}, {id: 'xyz', name: 'Somebody 2'}];
let humansConvertedToMap = arrayOfObjectsToMapByKey(humans, 'id')
let abcName = humansConvertedToMap[id].name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and map the key/value pairs to the constructor.

```js
let humans = [{ id: 'abc', name: 'Somebody 1' }, { id: 'xyz', name: 'Somebody 2' }],
    humansMap = new Map(humans.map(o => [o.id, o])),
    abcName = humansMap.get('abc').name;

console.log(abcName);
```